# How to get redirected URL on Android?

Tags: java, android, http, url, redirect

I can do it in java with this code:

```
  String url = "http://t.co/i5dE1K4vSs";

  URLConnection conn = new URL( url ).openConnection();
  System.out.println( "orignal url: " + conn.getURL() );
  conn.connect();
  System.out.println( "connected url: " + conn.getURL() );
  InputStream inputS = conn.getInputStream();
  System.out.println( "redirected url: " + conn.getURL() );
  inputS.close();
```

Now in android when a button is clicked it calls :

```
public void followRedirects(View v) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, URISyntaxException
{
  String url = "http://t.co/i5dE1K4vSs";

  URLConnection conn = new URL( url ).openConnection();
  System.out.println( "orignal url: " + conn.getURL() );
  conn.connect();
  System.out.println( "connected url: " + conn.getURL() );
  InputStream inputS = conn.getInputStream();
  System.out.println( "redirected url: " + conn.getURL() );
  inputS.close();
}
```

This is my error log in android 
[image]

Comment: I think you need to add the respective permissions in the manifest file. Did you add network permission ?

Answer (score 1):

Like you see the bottom-most exception is `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. To ensure performance, Android SDK prevents developers (and their applications) to make non-local connections and their operations on the main (UI) thread. You can use the same code snippet you posted, you only need to make sure it's running on a non-UI thread.

E.g.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        followRedirects(null);
    }
}).start();
```

Or if you want it to be executed on click:

```
 public void followRedirects(View v) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, URISyntaxException
{
  new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        String url = "http://t.co/i5dE1K4vSs";

        URLConnection conn = new URL( url ).openConnection();
        System.out.println( "orignal url: " + conn.getURL() );
        conn.connect();
        System.out.println( "connected url: " + conn.getURL() );
        InputStream inputS = conn.getInputStream();
        System.out.println( "redirected url: " + conn.getURL() );
        inputS.close();
    }
  }).start();
}
```

Comment: I love reputation farmers ... This question should be marked as duplicate ...

Comment: If I do that it gives me some unhandled exceptions...